# STDOUT a file - perl

Tags: regex, perl, stdout

Okay so I have my file read in and it prints nicely, but now I am trying to output data to a new file and it isn't working. Can anyone see whats wrong here?

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

$| = 1;

open MYFILE, "+<", 'source_file.txt' or die $!;
my $linenum = 1;
while (<MYFILE>) {
    print $linenum++;
    print ": $_\n";
}

open OUT, "+>", 'output_report.txt' or die $!;
while (<OUT>) {
print "SUMMARY SECTION:\n\n";
print "# of total lines in the file - '2006'\n\n";

}
```

The new file 'output_report' was created but when I go to open the new txt file, it is to my misfortune, blank. Also, do I HAVE to use STDERR if I am using STDOUT? Thanks ahead!

Comment: what do you mean about STDERR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
while (<OUT>) {
    print ...
    print ...
}
```

to:

```
print OUT ...
print OUT ...
```

`<>` is for reading, not writing.  Your code is reading from the file, which is empty, so it never even enters the loop (which would have printed out to STDOUT, not the file).

Also, if you are just reading, use `<`, not `+<`.  If you are just writing, use `>`, not `+>`.  The other modes are for doing a mix of reading and writing to the same file.

Comment: it wont hurt my program if I leave the + marks in though right? because I am not sure what I specifically need yet.

Answer (score 1):

" OUT in angle brackets " `<OUT>` is used for reading, not for writing. Use the below thing for writing.

```
print "SUMMARY SECTION:\n\n";
print "# of total lines in the file - '2006'\n\n";
```

Instead of above, use

```
print OUT "SUMMARY SECTION:\n\n";
print OUT "# of total lines in the file - '2006'\n\n";
```

Try out this link: http://www.perlfect.com/articles/perlfile.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call [`close`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) when you are done with the file, so the buffers are flushed and the handle released.

Comment: That happens at the end of the script anyway.